# ReadOnlySequence<byte> and operations on SequencePosition

Tags: c#

I have to extract some bytes from a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` buffer which is a read result from a `PipeReader`.
Basically I search a beginning sequence and a terminating sequence, and get what there's in between.
It's all fine when the `SequencePosition` to use in the `Slice` method is the result from `PositionOf`, the problem comes when I need to get 1 byte more.

What I did is this (simplified):

```
ReadOnlySequence<byte> raw;
Span<byte> header;
byte terminator;

var header_pos = raw.PositionOf(header);
var terminator_pos = raw.PositionOf(terminator);

var almost_there = raw.Slice(header_pos.Value, terminator_pos.Value);
return raw.Slice(header_pos.Value, almost_there.Length + 1);
```

Obviously if I could avoid slicing twice it would be great, but this is not valid:
`var len = terminator_pos - header_pos;`
and this is not valid too:
`var end_pos = terminator_pos.Value + 1;`
so what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```cs
var end = raw.GetPosition(1, terminator_pos.Value);
return raw.Slice(header_pos.Value, end);
```